# JQuery return value of val() returns function?

Tags: jquery, return-value

This is my JQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  $('#formulario').change(function() {
    alert( $(this).val() );
    var nombreArchivo = $(this).val;
    nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo.replace(' ', '_');
    var ruta = '/printbox/views/formulariosweb/';
    $('#contenedorFormulario').load( ruta + nombreArchivo + '.html');
    $('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', ruta + nombreArchivo + '.css') );
  });

  $("#formulario").trigger('change');

});
```

This is HTML:

```
<select class="select" name="formulario" id="formulario">
          <?php
            foreach($listaForms as $form) {
              echo "<option value=\"{$form}\">{$form}</option>";
            }
          ?>
        </select>
```

I get:

```
TypeError: nombreArchivo.replace is not a function

nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo.replace(' ', '_');
```

Looking at nombreArchivo values in the inspector, says it's of type function().

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jorge, you forgot to mark the answer as correct...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
$(this).val()
```

instead of

```
$(this).val
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks